# Effective refractive index in waveguide

Tags: waveguide

Suppose we have thin film with complex refractive index $n=4+1.5i$ placed on top of glass substrate. Does it make sense in this case to consider waveguide modes in the film? I used open source tools (femwell) to define my geometry (film with 200 nm thickness) and source (700 nm) and now struggle to interpret the result. The output of the program predicts effective index of modes in this waveguide to be equal $n_{eff} = 3.8+1.5i$. What I really need is to somehow visualize excited mode in the plane of the film and to find the wavelength corresponding to the propagating wave (periodicity in the resulting picture). Is it correct to calculate this periodicity as $\frac{\lambda}{n_{\text{eff}}}$ or $\frac{\lambda}{\textrm{Re} \:n_{\text{eff}}}$?